# Switch in ssrs expression Not reading all conditions

Tags: reporting-services

Can anyone tell me why this will not read the every condition.

```
=SWITCH(Fields!RepoRate.Value < .14, "82%", 
Fields!RepoRate.Value > .15, "79%", 
Fields!RepoRate.Value > .20, "Recourse Only")
```

This is used in an expression for a column in a report via ssrs.  It will only return 82% and 79%, I have also added after "Recourse Only", 0) Still does not read the Recourse Only, is this a string issue?

Comment: The second condition pass before than the third. Change second to `Fields!RepoRate.Value > .15 and Fields!RepoRate.Value <= .20`

Answer (score 3):

Switch conditions are evaluated in order, from first to last.

As soon as a condition is found to be true, the value associated with it is returned, and the rest of the conditions are ignored.

If a RepoRate.Value is greater than .20, then it will also be greater than .15, so it will meet the second criteria and never get tested against the third.

You should switch the order of the second and third lines.

And by the way, what if the RepoRate is either .14 or .15?